# R code not running when using Ruby

Tags: ruby, r

The commented line below throws an error: unsupported data type on R's end. Can someone tell me why?

```
require "rinruby"  
ck=0
begin
R.eval <<EOF
  eve<-read.csv("RExportWithTotals2015-02-18.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
  ck=1
  regModel<-lm(eve$npitotal~eve$extraversion+eve$agreeableness)
  ck=2
  ss<-summary(regModel)
  ck=3
  call<-ss$call
EOF

ck=4
puts "#{R.call}"#-------------------ERROR HERE"
rescue Exception=> ex
puts "#{ex.message}\nerror line: #{ck}"
end
```

using Ruby version 2.0.0, latest RinRuby gem (gem install rinruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to typecast call as a string for Ruby like so:

```
puts "#{R.pull "toString(call)"}"
```